# How can I vertically and horizontally center 3 100x100px divs while keeping them in row

Tags: html, css, position

I've been coding in HTML and CSS for only about 6 months, I need to center 3 divs with height and widths of 100px and border-radius %100

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go:

```
.wrap {
text-align: center;
position:absolute;
margin:auto;
left:0; right:0;
top:0; bottom:0;
width:100%;
height:100px;
display:block;
}

div div {width: 100px; 
height: 100px; 
background: #30353b; 
border-radius: 100%; 
display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/drukaman/paohy1bc/

Comment: Thank you, I forgot position:absolute;

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.wrap {text-align: center;}
div div {width: 100px; height: 100px; background: #30353b; border-radius: 100%; display: inline-block;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrap">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Or with vertical centering too ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.wrap {display: table; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin: -50px 0 0 -150px;}
div div {width: 100px; height: 100px; background: #30353b; border-radius: 100%; display: inline-block;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrap">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is what I have been getting, I need it to be vertically centered as well

Comment: You didn't stipulate that. Updated, although I see you've chosen another method anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery you can set what you want.

try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<style>

.wrap {
    text-align: center;
}
div div {width: 100px; height: 100px; background: #30353b; border-radius: 100%; display: inline-block;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrap">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    var windowH = $( document ).height();
    var divH = $('.wrap').height();
    var result = (windowH-divH)/2;

    $('.wrap').css({'margin-top':result});
})

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It didn't vertically center